# Are there squeeze-versions of ring and abel?

Tags: lean, lean3, lean-mathlib, performance

In Lean, it is recommended to use `squeeze_simp` to generate `simp only [a bunch of lemmas]` for two reasons:

(1) Otherwise the behaviour of `simp` might change, when for example `mathlib` is changed.

(2) The proof-verification runs faster, since `simp` does not have to try all lemmas.

I am wondering whether there are similar commands for other tacticts, such as `ring` or `abel`. If I understand correctly, the behaviour (point (1)) is fixed, but for point (2) this could lead to an improvement.

Concretely, I have a long proof that uses a bunch of `abel` and it returns a `deterministic timeout`, so I would like to speed it up.

Comment: No, there isn't. You could try `show_term { ... }` and replace it with that, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `ring` and `abel` produce a proof term that is going to be about as good as you could hope for from a putative `squeeze_ring` or `squeeze_abel`. This explains the suggestion from the comment to use `show_term { ring }`. However you will quickly find that for all but the most trivial examples, this will produce very large proof terms that you will not want to copy and paste into your source file!

The general answer to "I have a long proof and ..." is to split your proof into many smaller lemmas. (I aim for at most 10 lines, and if the proof "has to" be longer, to make sure there are human-readable expository comments at least every ten lines.) Smaller lemmas are usually easier for humans to digest, and more maintainable, as well as often faster to elaborate (and less likely to hit the deterministic timeout limit).